# Playing media using asynctask(android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play media at different intervals.
I have a function that plays the media void playAudio() and when ever a media file is played a asynctask is executed to start calculating the time for the next media.

The intervals are calculated in the doInBackground() method of my asynctask. When the interval is up the onPostExecute function calls that playAudio() function.
So after the first media file is played the app crashes.
Help please!

```
public void startNextFile() {

    if (mCompleted < nums.size()) {
        int a=Integer.parseInt(nums.get(c++));



        currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        mp[mCompleted] = MediaPlayer.create(this, songIds[a]);


        mp[mCompleted].start();
        ArrayList<String> payload=new ArrayList<String>(0);

        payload.add(++mCompleted+"");
        payload.add(differences.get(mCompleted-1));
        payload.add(currentTime+"");

        AsyncTask thread=new AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>,Void,Boolean>(){

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(ArrayList<String>[] strings) {
                //int idx= Integer.parseInt(strings[0].toString());
                long diff=Long.parseLong(strings[1].toString());
                long current_time=Long.parseLong(strings[2].toString());
                boolean isTime=false;
                while(!isTime)
                {
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis()-current_time==diff)
                    {
                        isTime=true;
                    }
                }
                return isTime;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
                startNextFile();

            }
        };

        thread.execute(payload);



    }
    else
    {
        mCompleted=0;
    }
}
```

Edit:
So, after checking the logcat it seems there is this error:
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList[]
                                                                               at com.example.cracked.pianist.Player$2.doInBackground(Player.java:208)"

208 is the line where Async task starts

Updated code just to check the doInBackground function

```
public void startNextFile() {

    if (mCompleted < nums.size()) {
        int a=Integer.parseInt(nums.get(c++));



        currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        mp[mCompleted] = MediaPlayer.create(this, songIds[a]);


        mp[mCompleted].start();
        ArrayList<String> payload=new ArrayList<>(0);
        //Toast.makeText(Player.this,"starting thread",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        payload.add(++mCompleted+"");
        payload.add(differences.get(mCompleted-1)+"");
        payload.add(currentTime+"");

        AsyncTask thread=new AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>,Void,Integer>(){

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(ArrayList<String>[] arrayLists) {
                //int idx= Integer.parseInt(arrayLists[0].get(0));
                //long diff=Long.parseLong(arrayLists[0].get(1));
                //long current_time=Long.parseLong(arrayLists[0].get(2));
                //long current_time=System.currentTimeMillis();

                int count=Integer.parseInt(arrayLists[0].get(0));
                //boolean isTime=false;
                //Log.d("starting","loop starting");
                /*while(!isTime)
                {
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis()-current_time==diff)
                    {
                        isTime=true;
                    }
                }*/
                return count;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
                super.onPostExecute(integer);
                Log.d("error","size is: "+integer);
                Toast.makeText(Player.this,"Thread done "+integer,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };

        thread.execute(payload);



    }
    else
    {
        mCompleted=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing ArrayList instead of String value for parseLong() method. That's why your getting class cast exception.

Change this

```
long diff=Long.parseLong(strings[1].toString());
long current_time=Long.parseLong(strings[2].toString());
```

to

```
long diff=Long.parseLong(strings[0].get(0));
long current_time=Long.parseLong(strings[0].get(1));
```

and if you need any other help then let me know.

Comment: thanks i understand the mistake i was making by accessing the wrong index. But after correcting this mistake the same error persists:java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList[]
                                                                                 at com.example.cracked.pianist.Player$2.doInBackground(Player.java:208)

Comment: even if i simply just return the length of string or return string[0].size to show a Toast in the onPostExecute method and remove all other code from doInBackground. The app crashes with the same error.

Comment: Remove all code from doInBackground and only print string[0].get(0) value  in log cat , if it correct then do as I answered may be your problem get solved.

Comment: So i tried something, i created a separate java file for AsyncTask and that does not seem to cause any problem. But in that AsyncTask how do i call a public method startNextFile() that is in the Threads calling Activity?

Comment: make an object of new class and call that method